# Vue Watch for class change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling

I would like to listen for a class change. If the button got "fully-in-viewport" then to trigger click. `$( "button.in-viewport.fully-in-viewport" ).trigger( "click" );`
Found for many other options but nothing with on class change. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you do this?

Comment: Since Vue don't support trigger function in viewport.
I bind class when in viewport > hidden button > trigger click(func).

Answer (score 30):

You could use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to observe class changes, and react according to the new class value:

1. Add a `ref` to the element to observe:

   ```
   <button ref="myButton">foo</button>
   ```
2. Create a method to handle observed changes:

   ```
   methods: {
     onClassChange(classAttrValue) {
       const classList = classAttrValue.split(' ');
       if (classList.includes('fully-in-viewport')) {
         console.log('has fully-in-viewport');
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create a `MutationObserver` that observes changes to the `class` attribute of the `ref` element, which will call the method defined above:

   ```
   mounted() {
     this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
       for (const m of mutations) {
         const newValue = m.target.getAttribute(m.attributeName);
         this.$nextTick(() => {
           this.onClassChange(newValue, m.oldValue);
         });
       }
     });

     this.observer.observe(this.$refs.myButton, {
       attributes: true,
       attributeOldValue : true,
       attributeFilter: ['class'],
     });
   },
   beforeDestroy() {
     this.observer.disconnect();
   },
   ```

```js
Vue.component('foo', {
  template: `<button ref="myButton" class="foo" @click="onClick">foo</button>`,
  mounted() {
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      for (const m of mutations) {
        const newValue = m.target.getAttribute(m.attributeName);
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.onClassChange(newValue, m.oldValue);
        });
      }
    });

    this.observer.observe(this.$refs.myButton, {
      attributes: true,
      attributeOldValue : true,
      attributeFilter: ['class'],
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.observer.disconnect();
  },
  methods: {
    onClassChange(classAttrValue) {
      const classList = classAttrValue.split(' ');
      if (classList.includes('fully-in-viewport')) {
        this.$refs.myButton.click();
      }
    },
    onClick() {
      requestIdleCallback(() => {
        alert('foo clicked');
      });
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    active: false
  }),
})
```

```css
.foo {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" @change="active = !active">
      <code>.fully-in-viewport</code> class
    </label>
  </div>
  <foo :class="{'fully-in-viewport': active}"></foo>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the high-quality answer. Note for Vue 3, if you are using Composition API (you should, it's fantastic), replace beforeDestroy() with onBeforeUnmounted(), then put the observer instantiation outside onMounted(), like: "const observer = null" so it can be used by both onMounted and onBeforeUnmounted.

Comment: A little late to the show, but for anyone else finding this answer and it's not working... if you're using the latest Vue 2 you're going to want to change the line `this.observer.observe(this.$refs.myButton, {` to `this.observer.observe(this.$refs.myButton.$el, {` (notice the `.$el`) because the observer is looking for the Node and not the Vue ref itself. Clever answer though.

Comment: @Tomas Thanks for the extra tip! I always appreciate helpful comments to improve my answer. But last I checked, your suggestion would only be needed if `this.$refs.myButton` were a Vue component. If the template ref were on a native element (i.e., like in the answer), `$el` would not be defined. Let me know if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @tony19 Yes, that is correct... I think it makes sense to mention both. If it's a Vue component you would need to use $el. I'm too used to working mainly with Vuetify where almost all the code is made up of components.